# Loading PHP Extensions using Plesk

Tags: php, windows-server-2008, plesk, php-extension

I am trying to load the `php_memcache.dll` extension using the Plesk **Additional Directives** section under the **PHP Settings** for a domain, subscription or subdomain. No matter what I do, I cannot get Plesk to load the extension!

The only way I can load the extension into PHP is by manually editing the `php.ini`, which is  a dirty fix as I will need to edit this each time the server is updated as the `php.ini` gets overwritten each time!

**The `php_memcache.dll` is definitely in the extensions directory referenced in the `phpinfo()`, this is proven by the fact that I can load the extension successfully by entering it into the `php.ini` manually.**

I am pretty confident this is a bug, but just wanted to see if anybody else has had any similar issues?

Comment: I have the same problem. :) Haven't found a solution yet. (Platform: Windows, Plesk: v11)

Answer (score 0):

The bug seems to be the description implying that it is possible when it really is not.

In this page: http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP11/11.5/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-administrator-guide/index.htm?fileName=69696.htm it says that additional directives can take any setting that is listed as PHP_INI_USER and PHP_INI_ALL in this page: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php.

In that page extension is listed as php.ini only, so it will not work from the additional directives option.